# The law of the excluded-middle in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, beth-tableau

As a simple exercise in modal logic, I'd like to show that $\not\vdash\Diamond(p\lor\neg p)$. However, when using the tableaux method, I can't get very far. After replacing $\neg\Diamond$ with $\Box\neg$, there are no previously introduced worlds in which to apply $\Box$. If I try to introduce "all" possible worlds, it seems like the branch is closed (so probably this is illicit?).

$$\neg\Diamond(p\lor\neg p),0\\ \Box\neg(p\lor\neg p),0\\ p,1\\ \neg p,1\\p,2\\ \neg p,2\\p,3\\ \neg p,3\\ \vdots\\ \times$$

I need to show that this tree has (at least) one open branch in order to prove $\not\vdash \Diamond(p\lor\neg p)$.

Comment: What is your axiom system? Plenty of modal logics *do* have $\vdash p\vee\neg p$ (e.g. $p\vee\neg p$ is valid in all Kripke frames).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You say that you want to show $\not \vdash p \lor \neg p$ -- but then where do your $\neg \Diamond (p \lor \neg p)$ and $\Box \neg(p \lor \neg p)$ come from? Are you trying to model derivability ($\vdash$) via modal operators ($\Box, \Diamond$)? These are not the same thing! While it is possible to use the language of modal logic to formalize arguments about derivability in logic -- if that's what you were having in mind -- you can not simply identify $\vdash \phi$ with $\vdash \Box \phi$ or $\vdash \Diamond \psi$!

Comment: Also, to show that a derivation with all branches closed does not exist, it does *not* suffice to present just one tableau with an open branch -- you have to argue that *any* attempt at completing the tableau will have open branches, that is, you have to provide an explanation along with your tableau showing why no other rule applications will lead to success.

Comment: Also, as pointed out in the other comment, whether we have $\vdash p \lor \neg p$ or $\not \vdash p \lor \neg p$ will depend on which rule system you are talking about. Since your formula doesn't have any modal operators in it, we don't need the clutter of modal logic with its different systems, as its (non-)derivability will coincide with that in non-modal standard logic. If you're talking about modal classical logic, then we have $\vdash p \lor \neg p$. If you are talking about e.g. (modal) intuitionistic logic, where we indeed have $\not\vdash p \lor \neg p$, you need to make this explicit.

Comment: But we can't use tableaux for intuitionistic logic, so that can't be what you're talking about. So: 1) What exactly are you trying to prove, and if what you're after is the existence or non-existence of a tableau for $p \lor \neg p$, where do your two modal formulas (and why to of them) come from, and 2) which logic, i.e. 2a) which underlying logic (classical, intuitionistic, minimal, ...?) logic and 2b) which modal system (K, T, S5, ...) are you using?

Comment: And a last point: Why are you referring to $p \lor \neg p$ as "the law of non-contradiction"? This is not the law of non-contradiction. That would be $\neg (p \land \neg p)$, which is derivable in both classical and intuitionistic logic. $p \lor \neg p$ is the "law of the excluded middle", and holds only in classical logic.

Comment: @lemontree, I'm not very familiar with modal logic, just reading Graham Priest's "Non-Classical Logic". I think he is using $K$, but I'm not sure? He presents the OP as an exercise. You're correct, I meant "law of excluded middle". The tableaux method for modal logic can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux#Tableaux_for_modal_logics

Comment: Okay, so the modal system is K -- this still leaves the other questions open: 1. Which underlying logical system are you working in? Priests book covers classical logic,  intuitionistic logic, many-valued logics, relevant logics, ... In which of those systems would you like to show the underivability of $p \lor \neg p$ in? The modal system K can combine with any of those logics.

Comment: 2. And again: If it's $p \lor \neg p$ you want to construct a tableau for, where do the modal operators suddenly come from? If they are not part of the goal formula $p \lor \neg p$, there is no rule in the tableau method which allows us to just introduce them. If you want have an open tableau that unsuccessfully attempts to falsify $p \lor \neg p$, then the formula you need to start with is $\neg (p \lor \neg p)$; the $\Diamond$ you put there just appears out of nowhere. This is not according to the rules of the tableau method.

Comment: @lemontree: Oh! I made a huge typo in the original prompt. I just corrected it: I'm trying to show $\not\vdash\Diamond(p\lor\neg p)$. That's where the modal operators come from. As for the type of logic, I don't think Priest's book has covered this distinction yet, so presumably it's classical logic?

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Doubt I updated my answer with a simple countermodel we can construct from the open branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly say, you start your tableau with

$\neg \Diamond(p \lor \neg p), 0\\
\Box \neg (p \lor \neg p), 0$

And that's where it already ends: In order to continue by disassembling $\Box$, you'd need to have a $0$-accessible world $1$ in your branch, $0r1$. This is what the rule in Priest's book states:

> $\Box A, i\\ irj\\ \downarrow\\ A, j$

Here, $A$ is the formula $\neg(p \lor \neg q)$, $i$ is $0$, and $j$ is $1$.

But we do not have such a statement $0r1$: The world $1$ has nowhere been introduced. You can't just make the label $1$ up, it *must* have been introduced into the branch beforehand as $0r1$ by an application of the $\Diamond$ rule -- but **you don't have a formula starting with $\Diamond$ in your branch, and hence no world $1$ to continue with.**

The semantic motivation for this restriction is the following:
If we have a formula of the form $\Diamond A, i$, then we know by the semantics of $\Diamond$ that there exists a possible world $j$ accessible from $i$ such that $A$ holds at $j$, so the rule for $\Diamond$ requires us to introduce this world  into the branch by writing $irj$ (where $r$ stands for "*r*eaches" or "accessibility *r*elation").
However, if by $\Box$ we make a claim about all the possible worlds $j$ that are accessible from $i$, then we need to make sure that these worlds $j$ actually exist: $\Box A, i$ states that "For all worlds $j$, *if* $j$ is accessible from $i$, *then* $A$ holds at $j$". This statement tells us nothing about the existence of $i$-accessible worlds: The formula $\Box A, i$ can become vacuously true if there are no $i$-accessible worlds at all; and even if there are worlds that $i$ can access, then according to the "if"-clause we need to restrict ourselves to those worlds of which we know that $i$ can access them, and are not allowed to just make up claims about new worlds that we have never seen on the branch before. So we need to make use of those worlds that we know exist and are accessible from $i$, namely those that have already been introduced in the branch as $irj$.
Hence, according to the definition of the $\Box$ rule, in order to go from $\Box \neg(p \lor \neg q), 0$ to a world $1$, we need to have $0r1$ already present in the branch.

But this is not the case here. Also, since the only thing we did so far is the conversion from $\neg \Diamond$ to $\Box \neg$ (which was the only option available at that time), it is obvious that at no point we could have chosen a different rule application that would enable us to continue the tableau. (This part is important: **In order to show $\not \vdash$, i.e. to prove that no syntactic derivation (e.g. no tableau) exists, it does *not* suffice to present just one unsuccessful (in the case of tableaus: open) derivation -- instead, we need to argue why *any* attempt of setting up a proof will eventually fail.)** Since there is no other way to construct the tableau such that will eventually be closed, we proved that there is no tableau refutation for the formula $\Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$: We successfully proved $\not\vdash \Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$.

---

From this open branch it is straightforward to construct a countermodel that refutes the validity ($\not \vDash$) of the formula. Since our problem was that we know of no $0$-accessible world that could serve to refute $\neg(p \lor \neg p)$, setting up our countermodel is very simple: We just create a structure with only one world, which can reach nothing and in which nothing holds:

[image]

Let $\mathfrak{A} = \langle W, R, v \rangle$ with
$W = \{w_0\}$,
$R = \emptyset$,
$v: \langle P,w \rangle \mapsto 0$ for any propositional letter $P$ and world $w \in W$

Since $w_0$ can't reach any worlds at all, trivially there is no reachable world in which $p \lor \neg p$ holds,

- hence $w_0 \not \vDash \Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$
  ($\Diamond(p \lor
     \neg p)$ is not true in the world $w_0$, since $p \lor \neg p$ is not true in any
  $w_0$-accessible world),
- hence $\mathfrak{A} \not \vDash \Diamond(p
     \lor \neg p)$
  ($\Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$ is not true in the structure
  $\mathfrak{A}$, since it is not true in all $w \in W$),
- hence $\not
     \vDash \Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$
  ($\Diamond(p \lor \neg p)$ is not
  valid, since it is not true in all structures).